# I am having a problem scraping a table from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have web scraped a few tables before but now it seems like it's just not working. The code is very simple - just the beginning 10 or so lines. I can't specifically get the details for the table; the program keeps returning `table` as the value for the variable table, in which I am trying to store the table. Super confused. Would appreciate some assistance!!

```py
# from selenium import webdriver 
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
# import pandas as pd 
# import time 

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/team-stats'

page = requests.get(url) 
page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

table = soup.find('table', {'class' : "tablesaw tablesaw-swipe"})
table
```

**I expected to get the html for the table, however I got the output below. Also, the variable soup returns the correct information.**

**Output:**

```
In[28]: runfile('/Users/dannyscott/Documents/Python Web Scraping/discord bot code V1.py', wdir='/Users/dannyscott/Documents/Python Web Scraping')
```

```
In[29]: table
```

**also, if I try to `table.find_all` , it will say *"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all''"***

Answer (score 0):

> **Output:**
>
> ```
> In[28]: runfile('/Users/dannyscott/Documents/Python Web Scraping/discord bot code V1.py', wdir='/Users/dannyscott/Documents/Python Web Scraping')
> ```
>
> ```
> In[29]: table
> ```

These don't look like outputs - they look more like commands from the console [or something] that just don't have any outputs. Speaking of which, if you run code with one output and have multiple  statements that return something [like just `page.text`/`soup`/`table` in your code], then only the last statement's return will  show up. If you want to view them all, you should [`print`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) them instead.

---

> **also, if I try to `table.find_all` , it will say *"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all''"***

If you tried `print(table)` you would probably see nothing, but if you tried `print([table])` you might have seen **`[None]`** in the output; and that's also the reason for the error - no `table` with that class was found, and you can't apply `find...` to a null value.

---

> ```py
> table = soup.find('table', {'class' : "tablesaw tablesaw-swipe"})
> ```

When the expected element is not found, you can try widening the search with something like *`tables = soup.find_all('table')`* to [see all the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zoz1.png) or just print the classes, row count and some of the text from each table with

```py
for t in soup.find_all('table'): 
    rows = f"[{len(t.select('tr')):>2} rows]"
    txtPrevw = ' '.join(t.get_text(' ').split())
    if len(txtPrevw) > 100: txtPrevw = txtPrevw[:97] + '...'
    print(f"> {str(t.get('class')):>20}", rows, ' --> ', txtPrevw)
```

output:

> ```
>   ['game', 'played'] [ 5 rows]  -->  Final Score Boston (28-12) at San Antonio (13-27) 121 116 Box Score Regular Season
>       ['game_stats'] [ 1 rows]  -->  Box Score Regular Season
> ['game', 'unplayed'] [ 5 rows]  -->  8:00 PM ET Utah (20-21) at Chicago (18-21) Preview Regular Season
>       ['game_stats'] [ 1 rows]  -->  Preview Regular Season
> ['game', 'unplayed'] [ 5 rows]  -->  8:00 PM ET New Orleans (24-15) at Dallas (22-17) Preview Regular Season
>       ['game_stats'] [ 1 rows]  -->  Preview Regular Season
> ['game', 'unplayed'] [ 5 rows]  -->  8:30 PM ET Orlando (14-25) at Golden State (20-19) Preview Regular Season
>       ['game_stats'] [ 1 rows]  -->  Preview Regular Season
> ['game', 'unplayed'] [ 5 rows]  -->  10:00 PM ET L.A. Lakers (18-21) at Sacramento (20-17) Preview Regular Season
>       ['game_stats'] [ 1 rows]  -->  Preview Regular Season
>         ['tablesaw'] [31 rows]  -->  # Team GP MPG PPG FGM FGA FG% 3PM 3PA 3P% FTM FTA FT% ORB DRB RPG APG SPG BPG TOV PF 1 Boston 40 ...
> ```

---

I'm not sure if this is the one you were trying to get, but with **`soup.find('table', {'class' : "tablesaw"})`** you can get this table:

[image: table.tablesaw]